# Desktop on boot up says failed to start snap.canon...al

Tags: boot, startup, steam

I had steam open updating a game and then the desktop went to sleep and when I woke up the desktop the screen went white which was steam so I closed out steam and it wouldn't reopen so I figured just restart the desktop and when I did the error popped up and now I can't get past the boot up screen and take in mind I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and still learning a lot about it so please be simple In terms